# Are these rings the same? A detail in the Proj construction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, graded-rings, projective-schemes

The following detail is needed in the affine-by-affine gluing construction of the Proj of a graded rings. Every single reference that I know of takes the claim for granted.

Let $A$ be a nonnegatively graded ring, and let $f$ and $g$ be two homogeneous elements of positive degree. Then there should be isomorphisms of rings
$$\big((A_f)_0\big)_{g^{\deg f} / f^{\deg g}} \cong (A_{fg})_0 \cong \big((A_g)_0\big)_{f^{\deg g} / g^{\deg f}}$$
Here the subcript $0$ means '$0$-th graded part', while every other subscript denotes localisation at an element.

It is not clear to me at all why this should be true. I do not even have a conjectural map between the various rings, or any idea why $\deg f$ and $\deg g$ should appear.

Comment: If you "do not even have a conjectural map between the various rings", perhaps an example would be illuminating. Can you check what each of the various rings are when $A=k[x,y]$ with $x,y$ in degree one?

Comment: Being concrete, as KReiser suggests, is probably a good idea. More generally, whenever you're trying to write down a map out of a localization, it's probably a good idea to appeal to the universal property. A place to start on this problem would be to write down a map $(A_{f})_{0} \to (A_{fg})_{0}$ which allows you to use said universal property.

Comment: @KReiser If you start with an element $\big(f(x,y) / x^k\big) / \big(y^N / x^N\big)$ where $f(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, then you can rewrite this as $f(x,y) x^{2N - k} / x^N y^N$, I think, which gives the map from the left-hand side into the middle guy. (The rest should follow by symmetry.) But this seems an awfully weird map. It gets confusing if $x$ and $y$ have degrees, I think... Also I think you're gonna get troubles when $2N - k$ becomes negative, maybe.

Comment: Congratulations, that's the right map in general (replace $f(x,y)$ with an arbitrary element of $A$, multiply by $\frac{f}{f}$ and $\frac{g}{g}$ until the element has a denominator of the form $(fg)^c$ for some $c$). The extra degree stuff isn't actually so bad - it's occasionally a headache to keep track of, but it can be dealt with.

Comment: @KReiser Hmm. So maybe it wasn't as scary as I thought it was. Thanks, I'm gonna get a coffee and then meditate on it once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize the discussion from the comments so that this question may be marked as answered.

In the comments, after I suggested looking at an example, you discovered the correct map (in the case where $\deg f=\deg g$) - for an arbitrary element, we can rewrite it as follows: $$\frac{a/f^n}{(g^{\deg f}/f^{\deg g})^m}\mapsto \frac{af^{m\deg g}}{f^ng^{m\deg f}},$$  and then we just multiply by appropriate powers of $\frac{f}{f}$ and $\frac{g}{g}$ to get the bottom to be of the form $(fg)^c$ for some integer $c$ (you can solve this if you want - I don't think it's strictly necessary). The extra degree stuff is perhaps a clerical headache, but it can be dealt with.

Comment: Thank you for the summary so that I can mark the question as answered. :)